# Create a list with anchor tag inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of `<a>` tag inside my `<ul>` inside a `<div>`

## HTML

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1"> <span class="summary-texts">Summary </span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a class="group" id="group-a">Group A </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="group" id="group-b">Group B </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="group" id="group-c">Group C </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, they're hardcode in the HTML, and my goal is re-construct that list using JS.
I'm a little stuck trying to make that happen.

---

## I've tried

```
for (var assignment in objects.assignments ) {

  var dropdown = $("#dd").find(".dropdown");
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  dropdown.appendChild(entry);
  var a = createElement('a').appendTo(dropdown.find("li"));
  a.setAttribute('href', "" );
  a.innerHTML = "Group "+assignment;
}
```

---

### Error

> Uncaught TypeError: dropdown.appendChild is not a function

Can someone please give me a little help here ?

Any hints / helps / suggestions will be a huge help for me.

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and pure javascript, use `dropdown[0].appendChild` ==> javascript, or `dropdown.append(entry)` ==> jQuery.

Comment: I believe the jQuery find() method returns a set of elements, which is why I think you are getting the error with the appendChild function. Try iterating on the list of elements returned by find().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dropdown` is jQuery object, you cannot call `appendChild` methods on it.

Use `jQuery` to add/append elements as follow:

```
for (var assignment in objects.assignments) {
    $("#dd .dropdown")
        .append('<li><a href="">Group ' + assignment + '</a></li>');
}
```

Comment: I got quick question for your, is your answer will append to after my `<ul></ul>` OR with in the `<ul> IN HERE </ul>` ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of `dropdown.appendChild`, try `dropdown.append(li)`

.append() is jquery equivalent for Javascript appendChild